# Too many wild pixelmon spawned, how can I kill them?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-pixelmon

Due to excessive use of spawn boxes, too many wild pixelmon are walking around in my local game. This is slowing down the game to a crawl.

Is there an operator command to kill them easily and get the game back in a playable state?

Version is Forge 1.7.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume Pixelmon are registered as standard entities. If this is true, you can run `/kill @e` to kill all entities in the world.

Comment: Minecraft 1.7 does not have the `@e` selector.

Comment: Updating from 1.7 to 1.8 listed a couple block types as no longer known, in particular flowing lava and the pokedex. But after that, the command worked like a charm. Thanks!

Comment: Is there any way to do It without killing all players? I run a server with my friends and they don't appreciate getting killed

Answer (score 0):

I think you can only do so if you install a mod extra commands , including the command type; It's my supposition.

Or you 'll have to recreate the world , or start a new one.

You could create a new one and move buildings with outside editing programs.